# Bindings and NSButton

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, binding, nsbutton

Using bindings, how can I make NSButton invoke a method in my AppDelegate class? I tried setting the target sleector to buttonClicked: but in console it gives me:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x100105060

Also there's no place in bindings to specify which instance to look for the method in so how can I set it to AppDelegate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are used to synchronize a variable and an element of the interface.

In your case, I guess an *action* would be better. Declare your method with `IBAction` and control-drag from your button to your AppDelegate instance in Interface Builder to be able to select the action.

Answer (score 3):

As Simon says, bindings are not appropriate for this situation. Bindings allow you to "bind" UI elements to a data source. In your situation, you need an action - not a binding.

You are getting the error because you haven't actually defined the buttonClicked action. Thus, make sure you declare it with something like in your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id) sender;
```

Then set the action via interface builder by first setting the "FilesOwner" to the AppDelegate and then connecting the onTouchUpInside event to the action "buttonClicked".

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a Mac question, there's no `onTouchUpInside` event. You just need to set the action of the button to the declared action in the app delegate.

Comment: Weird, could've swore the tag was "iPhone". Oh well, you're right on Rob, thanks for the correction.